# dropbear dbclient + scp, equivalent to openssh "-oStrictHostKeyChecking"

Tags: linux, ssh, scp

Using dropbear's dbclient and scp implementation, is there a way to get the same behavior produced by openssh when using the scp option "-oStrictHostKeyChecking=no".

In other words, can I make dropbear's scp ignore the "Host $hostname is not in the trusted hosts file" warning?

The "dbclient" program will do this with the '-y' command line option, so it seems like it ought to be possible...  what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

A good workaround was provided at https://lists.ucc.gu.uwa.edu.au/pipermail/dropbear/2010q4/001078.html

The workaround described is to add a dbclient-noask script which does

```
#!/bin/sh
dbclient -y -y "$@"
```

and supply it to scp using the "-S" option.
Don't forget to give your helper script execute permission with `chmod`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it seems that there is a bug in dropbear and -y parameter is not passed to scp properly.

But do you really need to ignore "Host not in trusted host file"? Maybe what you should do is to add host key to .ssh/known_hosts file.
There is another bug in dropbear that causes scp not to read known_hosts when it is run as startup script.

I found info about both issues with dropbear and the solution here:

http://www.linksysinfo.org/index.php?threads/scp-wont-run-in-startup-script.68197/

If that is your issue, you simply need to set appropriate value of $HOME variable in your script i.e.

`export HOME=/path/to/home`  (/path/to/home should be parrent directory of your .ssh directory containing known_hosts)